# How to generate a lot of unique random strings in Scala

Tags: mysql, performance, scala, unique

I want to generate a lot of random strings that unique of each other and unique in MySQL with specify the number of generated like 10,000.

I could make sure the strings are unique each other in every time generated strings, just check if the `List[String]` contains the string in each time generate.
But I don't know how to make sure its unique in MySQL, I have been set the unique index in MySQL like

`` ALTER TABLE Code ADD UNIQUE INDEX `codeUnique` (`code`); ``

But if the unique guarantee is when inserting data into MySQL, insert will failure.
And if check the insert failure in each time insert, generating will take  a very very long time when the number of generated is large.

Answer (score 3):

Use `List.fill` and `randomUUID` as @Sudhir notes:

```
scala> List.fill(10000)(java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString)
res0: List[String] = List(
  3c789851-975c-499d-8b0b-5bc60dee7497, 
  9511fb41-a42e-47d8-a5f3-ba1a6f3847f2,
  61263421-59de-4538-87c6-eb98ccf1e19d, 
 ...)
```

You can double check they are unique by converting it to a set and checking the size:

```
scala> List.fill(10000)(randomUUID.toString).toSet.size
res1: Int = 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Java's `java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString` method to get unique `String`. See doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID--). Chances of getting duplicate keys using this method is very low (I never got duplicate keys). So you don't have to maintain a collection either.

If you want to use your own random key generator and want to make sure it's unique, you should not go for `List[String]` because `List` can have duplicates and for checking if a key already exists, you need to iterate over each elements, which is a costly operation. You should use `Set[String]` instead and then use `Set`'s `contains()` method to check if key is already present.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through 10000 integers, take the MD5 or SHA1 of each number.